# Is a Tomcat Cluster more effective than a single Tomcat?

Tags: tomcat, tomcat8

Just a quick question. Is a tomcat cluster with 3 Nodes of 4 gig ram better than having a single Tomcat with 12 gig ram allocation? Can you help explain why?

I am asking this question because we are running a high traffic application and we are getting out of memory crashes, heap error once in a while.

We are looking to improving our infra to become a highly available one. In doing so, what is the difference of having many small nodes with lesser ram each, than having one big node.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You may be interested in this question : http://serverfault.com/questions/412041/any-clear-benefit-in-having-multiple-tomcat-instances-behind-an-apache-server

Comment: Thank you! That thread, no clear answer too huh. But I understand looks like this is quite a tough scenario, with many possibilities. Thanks for sharing!